# Testing iPhone Mobile Device Management (MDM)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mdm

I am interested in testing Apple's MDM in my organization. It's unclear to me from Apple's [MDM page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/mdm/) . Should I work with an Apple-approved 3rd party provider or if I can create set up internally for testing ?

Or does that require apple approval as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing it is very hard.

You should go with the "Profil Manager" shipped with OSX Lion Server. Manage the whole MDM process.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this yourself. It does not require Apple approval. You need to webserver and code behind this to respond to the device.

It's not the easiest task in the world to create an MDM server, but, equally, it's not impossible if you have the MDM protocol documentation from Apple and a fair bit of patience!

If you do decide to create your own server, good luck!